# display difference between commits as in merge output

Tags: git

How do I get the difference between branches displayed in a format that gets outputted when you merge one branch into another? Example:

```
$ git merge random
Updating eb79f04..645485f
Fast-forward
 simple.html | 2 +-
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
```

EDIT1:
I can get a similar result with something like `git diff 0931ab1...eb79f04 --name-only` but that does not display the degree of change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`--stat`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---statltwidthgtltname-widthgtltcountgt) flag can do that.

```
git diff --stat <branch1> <branch2>
```

Alternatively, if you only need the `1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)` line, use [`--shortstat`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---shortstat) instead.